# nested aggregation elasticsearch with access parent field for sub-aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following mappings

```
PUT prod_nested
{
  "mappings": {
    "default": {
      "properties": {
        "pkey": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "original_price": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "category": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 30
                }
              }
            },
            "attribute": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 30
                }
              }
            },
            "original_price": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I am trying to do something like following sql aggregation

```
select tag_attribute,
       tag_category,
       avg(original_price)
FROM products
GROUP BY tag_category, tag_attribute
```

I am able to do the group-by part using nested aggregation on tags, but its not able to access the original_price in sub-aggregation. One option might be to duplicate the original_price inside the tags nested document, but I have millions of records to handle. My current aggregation is

```
GET prod_nested/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs": {
        "tags": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "categories": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tags.category.keyword",
                "size": 30
              },
              "aggs": {
                "attributes": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "tags.attribute.keyword",
                    "size": 30
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "price": {
                      "avg": {
                        "field": "original_price"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the desired results by using reverse_nested aggregation.

```
GET prod_nested/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "categories": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tags.category.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "attributes": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tags.attribute.keyword",
                "size": 10
              },
              "aggs": {
                "parent_doc_price": {
                  "reverse_nested": {},
                  "aggs": {
                    "avg_price": {
                      "avg": {
                        "field": "original_price"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want is not possible. 
but how about change your mapping?

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "default": {
      "properties": {
        "pkey": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "original_price": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "category_attribute": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 30
                }
              }
            },
            "category": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 30
                }
              }
            },
            "attribute": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 30
                }
              }
            },
            "original_price": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can use category_attribute. 
and your aggregation will be below.

```
GET prod_nested/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "category_attribute": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tags.category_attribute.keyword",
            "size": 30
          },
          "aggs": {
            "price": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "original_price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't tried your approach but I think that will work. However for my case I have been able to do a reverse_nested aggregation from within the nested aggregations to calculate the average price